# Medium Editor - Bold button/keyboard shortcut not working

Tags: javascript, medium-editor

I've installed [Medium Editor](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor) on our site, on two different pages.  They both work fine, and are initialised with the exact same code, but on one of pages the Bold button/shortcut doesn't work.

The page on which it doesn't work gets a lot more styling (and has a lot more js libraries) compared to the one that does work, and so I'm wondering if something else might be getting in the way.

I can't see any js errors in the console.  Has anyone encountered this problem?  I saw another forum [post](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/issues/908) saying it was something to do with styling on `font-weight`, but I can't see how this would actually stop the function working completely: it just seems to be disabled - the "B" button in the Medium Editor's popup menu doesn't change color when you click on it.

If it was a css issue I'd expect the button to change color but the text to not look different, perhaps, but it does just seem like "Bold" is disabled.  Also, any  tags already in the content's html do display ok.

Has anyone else encountered this, or other functions seemingly not working?

EDIT:  I just poked it some more and noticed that if something is bold already, and I highlight it, the B button does look activated, **and** and I can "unbold" it.  However, after unbolding the selected text, I can't "bold" it again.

EDIT2: More poking has revealed that if the highlighted text is set to be a heading, or is italicised, then I can bold and unbold it as intended.  So it's really just "normal" text which seems to be "bold-resistant".

Comment: The style inspector in devtools is designed precisely to solve these types of problems. it will show you exactly where each style is coming from.

Comment: @torazaburo what threw me off was that Medium Editor, for each formatting type, has a set of conditions which block the function of the button.  So, in this case, because the textarea had `font-weight:normal`, Medium effectively says "Don't bother with B on this, it's forced to be not-B already".  Once I knew that, I could see where the styling was coming from (using devtools as you say), but on the face of it, it wasn't at all obvious that that was what was happening - I only found out by reading the unminified source code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - the problem page had the text area inside a label tag, and so was picking up the styling for `label` across the site, which had `font-weight: 700`.  This was preventing Medium Editor from applying the Bold style to it.